# Creating batch file for applications on network servers

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

Every day, I use two programs, so I would like to try and create a batch file to load these programs with one click of the mouse, i.e. by clicking on an icon on the desktop.

The path to one of the programs is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Attachmate\Reflection\R02_Reflection
```

The file "type" is `Reflection for UNIX and OpenVMS Session`, or so I think. To be honest, it seems like it would be an `.exe` file type, but nothing I open seems to reveal that information.

The other file is on a network server *dedicated* to hosting that program's data files and software.

Given this information, do you think it's possible to write a batch file to accomplish such a task?

Comment: If you have an open folder, go Tools/Folder Options and go to 2nd tab called View. At #9 line it should say: "Hide extensions for known file types" un-check it and you should be able to view file extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS? On Windows XP, create a .bat file and play around with the `start` command. On Windows 7, a power shell script might be better. Create a .ps1 file and play around with `start-process` command. Then just create a desktop shortcut pointing to your script.

Comment: It's Windows XP Professional. The problem is, I can't tell what kind of extension the file is (as in .exe, .com, .bat, etc.). Any way to find that out for a file?

Comment: Just open it in notepad. If it's a .bat/.ps1, it'll be full of script commands. If it's a .exe, it's first two bytes will be MZ and it'll probably have "!This program cannot be run in DOS mode" somewhere on the first line (there are more precise definitions, but this is probably good enough for you). It's unlikely to be a .com

Comment: Did your recommendation about tools/folder options and apparently it's a .r2w file.

Comment: Then it's almost certainly a Reflection for Windows file, which is normally run from r2win (from memory and quick Google search). So your command line might be something like "<path>\r2win.exe Reflection for UNIX and OpenVMS Session.r2w"